# In Rails, can I query and only get objects that have a linked object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord, arel

So I have this object, let's call it Dog, and this other object, let's call it Collar.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :collar
end

class Collar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

Can I get **a list of dogs that have collars**? Ideally in a slightly less awkward way than the following:

```
Dog.joins(:collar).where(Collar.arel_table['id'].not_eq(nil))
```

As a note to those who might wonder about the "arel_table" bit, it is the DB-agnostic way of saying "IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `joins` directly

```
Dog.joins(:collar)
```

This will return dogs which have collar.

There is even no need to add `uniq` because this is has_one relation so no duplicate dogs will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

and what about just create scope in Collar or Dog model something like:

`scope :with_something, where( "foreign_key IS NOT NULL" )`

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but it feels like too much SQL and not enough AREL. `scope :with_collar, ->{ joins(:collar) }` sounds pretty cool though.